# Radical line thickness

Tags: fonts, symbols

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109576/change-sqrt-symbol) answer, I understand that `\radical` chooses the thickness of the horizontal line as a function of the height of a character.

Is there a way to redefine `\radical` so as we have control on the thickness? I would like end up with a slightly thicker line.

Edit: As a fallback solution, what if 1) we use LuaLaTeX, or 2) we just replace the “standard square root sign” (meaning, typeset in Computer Modern) with the square root sign of another font, e.g. STIX?

Comment: Which engine do you use?

Comment: I use pdflatex.

Comment: Then you can't change the thickness without changing the font.

Comment: But the horizontal line is drawn with some thickness that is computed, so it should be possible to find the definition of `\sqrt` in `amsmath` and adjust the thickness.

Comment: Not really, `\radical` is a TeX primitive which is implemented in the engine and not though TeX code.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If you are willing to switch to LuaTeX, then we would have options...

Comment: OK, if you answer below with some solution for LuaTeX, I will accept that answer.

Comment: I added an edit with questions that I believe can be answered more quickly.